# PHPUnit + Selenium 2 + PhantomJS で <input type="file"> のテストの書き方

Tags: php

タイトルの通りですが、 PHPUnit + Selenium 2 + PhantomJS で `<input type="file">` のテストの書き方（ `<input type="file">` に値を入力する方法）がわからず困っています。
（そもそも `<input type="file">` に対して PHPUnit から値を入力することが可能なのでしょうか...？）

下記は想定通り動作しなかったコードです。

```
$element = $this->byCssSelector('input[type="file"][name="file"]');
$element->value('/path/to/dummyimage01.png');
```

上記コードでは `<input type="file" name="file">` には何も入力されていませんでした。

当方の環境は下記の通りです。

- Mac OSX El Capitan (10.11.1)
- PHP: 5.5.24
- PHPUnit: 4.8.6
- Selenium: 2.47.1
- PhantomJS: 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit + Selenium 2でのアップロードのファイルの指定の仕方は、
https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/a6fdffdd56f4884ef39e09a9c62e5e4eb273e42c/Tests/Selenium2TestCase/SessionCommand/FileTest.php#L10
にあるように以下のようにします。

```
    $remote_file = $this->file('selenium-1-tests/html/banner.gif');
```

上記のコードそのままですが、アップロードは例えば以下のようになります。

```
    $this->url('php/file_upload.php');
    $remote_file = $this->file('selenium-1-tests/html/banner.gif');
    $this->byName('upload_here')
        ->value($remote_file);
    $this->byId('submit')
        ->click();
```

これで動作するはずですが、PhantomJS 2.0のファイルアップロードは壊れており機能しません。
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12506
これは、2.0.1で修正予定とのことです。

Comment: ブラウザを PhontomJS から Firefox に変更したところ、ご教示いただいた内容で動作することを確認しました！ありがとうございます！